# How do I map errors in rxJava?

Tags: java, exception, rx-java

How do I transform an error returned by an Observable in rxJava?
Now I have this method:

```
@Override
    public Maybe<JsonObject> getUser(String token) {
        return tokenManager.getTokenInfo(token)    //returns a Single<UserInfo>
            .flatMapMaybe(userInfo -> userRepo.findOne(userInfo));
    }
```

The behavior is that any exception that is passed by `getTokenInfo` or `findOne` is propagated to the subscriber of this function's return value. Is it possible to map the exceptions to something else? Like

```
@Override
    public Maybe<JsonObject> getUser(String token) {
        return tokenManager.getTokenInfo(token)
            mapError(exc -> new AuthException("invalid token"))  //don't let subscriber get raw exc
            .flatMapMaybe(userInfo -> userRepo.findOne(userInfo))
            .mapError(exc -> new NetworkException());


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onErrorResumeNext` with an `error` source of the desired exception:

```
return tokenManager.getTokenInfo(token)
       .onErrorResumeNext(exc -> Single.error(new AuthException("invalid token")))
       .flatMapMaybe(userInfo -> userRepo.findOne(userInfo))
       .onErrorResumeNext(exc -> Maybe.error(new NetworkException()));
```